# How to localize menu options in UITextView?

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

How can I localize menu options such as "Copy", "Look Up", "Learn...", etc. that appear when clicking on a UITextView? In apps like Twitter, these menus are displayed in the user's native language.

I was able to implement "Copy" by calling textView.copy() from a custom UIAction with a specific title, but I cannot use the same approach for "Look Up" because _define is a private API. Please advise on the correct way to implement this.

Comment: If your app is localized to a language that the user has set in their Settings then all Apple-provided labels will automatically show in that language.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by Add Row Localizations on the following screen and Add Row the language I want to support.

[Screenshot project>info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuSVW.jpg)

Thanks to HangarRash for the advice in the comments.